# syncdb-like tool for Kohana

Tags: django, kohana

I've used Django(python)  previously and now I'm learning Kohana (PHP). It seems to be good, but I wonder if there is something like "django-admin.py syncdb" in Kohana, or at least, a tool that makes the same job.

Comment: You should describe what `django-admin.py syncdb` does. The answer is likely "no" though.

Comment: @zombor The `syncdb` command creates tables and indexes in the database for the models in a django app.

Answer (score 0):

Django Model knows all information about their field before start working with database. Kohana Models, in contrast, knows only table name and on first using ORM authomaticaly calls ORM::list_columns() which executing  sql query

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `tablename`
```

and fill protected $_table_columns variable for this Model